# Error when adding variable

Tags: c, global-variables, pic

I'm writing a c-program for a pic24.
For some reason, i can only declare 7 global variables. When i add an eight one, the program compiles, but it won't run on the pic. I tested this with an unused variable

```
...
//int blabalabla;
...
```

The up program works, the program below doesn't:

```
...
int blabalabla;
...
```

Code:

```
#include "p24FJ64GA004.h"

_CONFIG2(FNOSC_PRIPLL & POSCMOD_XT)

#define RED2    LATBbits.LATB9
#define RED1    LATBbits.LATB8
#define GREEN2  LATBbits.LATB7
#define GREEN1  LATBbits.LATB6 
#define BLUE    LATBbits.LATB5

#define VSYNC   LATAbits.LATA1
#define HSYNC   LATAbits.LATA0

#define HSYNCUP         0x02DC  //  28us
#define HSYNCDOWN       0x0063  //  3.7us
#define HSYNCCYCLE      0x03F9  //  31.77us
#define VSYNCCYCLE      0x0350  //  32us
#define PIXELCOUNT      0x0049  //  2.8us

volatile int teller;

volatile int LINE;
volatile int ACTIVE;
volatile int ROW;
volatile int ENDROW;
volatile int number;
volatile int seconde;

int blablabla;

int bitmap[20][5] = {   {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {1,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {1,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,0}};

int main() {
...
}
```

Comment: ps: i have more than enough datamemory available

Comment: How about posting some complete, compilable, simple code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also what compiler are you using and what options are you passing to it?

Comment: MPLAB IDE v8.83, MPLAB C30 compiler, options: -g -Wall

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://books.google.se/books?id=cBdWD4YOj3QC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=pic24%20global%20variable%20limit&source=bl&ots=HcB6RWo89z&sig=Lqk5vDn53CcxLMGEhy0IsI8r8AQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UNpNT8k_p4XiBPuikf0C&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pic24%20global%20variable%20limit&f=false) mentions using PIC-specific keywords `near` and `far`, and also the existence of different memory models (small and large) that affect how you're supposed to use those keywords. You need to check these things.